# Why the FormInt64Control created by new() does not have method value?

Tags: axapta

I want to know why the FormInt64Control cread by new() does not have method value. For example when I run this code:

```
static void NewControlTest(Args _args)
{
    FormInt64Control FormInt64Control;
    FormInt64Control = new FormInt64Control();
    FormInt64Control.value(5);
    info(FormInt64Control.valueStr());
}
```

it will end with:

```
Object object does not have have method 'value'. 
Stack trace …
```

When the same thing is created on existing form using existing design (in run() for example).

```
formInt64Control = formGroupControl.addControl(FormControlType::Int64, "");
formInt64Control.value(5);
```

will run without problem. I would like to know how it is possible and how it is working behind. (In AX 2012 R3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do that: `new FormInt64Control()`. Just don't. Only create form controls using `addControl`.

To answer your question you need access to the C++ source code implementing the control. I do not have that access, nor do you.